# How to modify multiple columns and rows in a csv file using python 2.7.9

Tags: python, csv

I have a File1.csv having data (every data is on the new line, new row)

```
7F
1
4
FF
73
9F
7F
1
4
FF
73
9F
7F
1
4
FF
73
9F
```

I want to convert it into format shown below and save it as File2.csv

```
7F,1,4,FF,73,9F
7F,1,4,FF,73,9F
```

```
import csv #import the CSV module in python

f = open('File1.csv', "rb")

csv_f = [i for i in csv.reader(f)]
f.close()

tempVal1=csv_f[1]+csv_f[2]+csv_f[3]+csv_f[4]+csv_f[5]+csv_f[6]

tempVal2=csv_f[7]+csv_f[8]+csv_f[9]+csv_f[10]+csv_f[11]+csv_f[12]

with open('File2.csv', "wb") as csv_file:  #open the file to write, use "wb" for write access
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')    
    writer.writerow(tempVal1)     #write data into the file
    writer.writerow(tempVal2)     #write data into the file
```

I want to write above program in a efficient way (use for, while loops) so that I don't use tempVal1,2 variables also I want logic in my code where I can read '7F' value and write the data starting from 7F in new line separated by comma, can anyone help me?
My concerns are - 
1. How to read value in rows '7F'?
2. How to add for or while loop logic instead of putting additions and storing it in tempVal variable?

Comment: Do you always create a new line after `9F`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you create a new line after the `9f` value you can do:

```
import csv
with open("C:/path/a.txt","r") as f,open("C:/path/a.csv" ,"wb") as w:
    temp = []
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    for line in f:
        temp.append(line.strip())
        if "9F" in line:
            writer.writerow(temp)
            temp = []
```